# If I have 4 react components (let's say some custom buttons), how do I render them in a way that the last pressed is on top?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have been trying to do this but I just can't figure out how. I'm thinking about putting all those 4 buttons components in an array and then change the position to the 0th index if it was last pressed and then moving all the buttons to their index+1.

Is there a more react like way to do this?

Comment: With the assumption that the 0th index component will be at the top, yes you're on the right track. Hard to help more without any of your code. Typically you wouldn't store the components themselves in an array, instead you would store the data/props needed to build those components. Take a look here: https://coursework.vschool.io/mapping-components-in-react/

Comment: Create a copy of the array with slice, then `temp.unshift(temp.splice(clickedId, 1)[0])`?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, it sounds like a confusing user experience - usually I expect buttons to stay in one spot. That aside, there are plenty of ways to do this; here's one.

You could keep a state object with each of the four button names as keys, and epoch millis as values. That will make it easy to compare the last pressed time. Something like:

```js
const [lastPressedTimes, setLastPressedTimes] = useState({
  button1: 1, // initial order
  button2: 2,
  button3: 3,
  button4: 4,
});
const sortedButtonNames = Object.values(lastPressedTimes)
  .sort(([, aTime], [, bTime]) => bTime - aTime) // descending order
  .map(([name]) => name);

return (
  <>
    {sortedButtonNames.map((name) => (
      <YourButton
        name={name}
        key={name}
        onPress={() => setLastPressedTimes({
          ...lastPressedTimes,
          [name]: new Date().getTime(),
        })}
      />
    )}
  </>
);
```

Whenever a button is pressed, the state will be updated so that the last pressed button time is stored under its name.